# How to set source quantity (MSI) from my own custom backend module in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2.4, msi

I'm new to M2, and I am in a hurry to migrate my site from M1. In M1 I made my own MSI functionality, but now I would like to use the built in MSI functionality in M2.
For some of the backend logic (like moving item stock from one source to another when needed), I have created my own module. The logic works, but I need to be able to update the quantity on a specific source.

**I would like to know how to set new qty to a specific source for a specific sku in a custom module.**

I've been at it for a week with no success. I have found answers to similar questions, but the answers are quote code, but do not say specifically where to put the code.

Seems like I should be able to use SourceItemsProcessor, but I don't know the basics in M2 on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_sourceItemsSaveInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface');
$_sourceItemFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterfaceFactory');
$sourceItem = $_sourceItemFactory->create();
$sourceItem->setSourceCode('store_code'); // default : stock source
$sourceItem->setSku($product_sku);
$sourceItem->setQuantity(100);
$sourceItem->setStatus(1);
$_sourceItemsSaveInterface->execute([$sourceItem]);
```

hope this helps you. accept solution if works for you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I have, but since I am new to the forum, it will not show the upvote yet.

Comment: ok..no worries ..happy to hear it helps ..thanx for accept answer. :)

Comment: @GohilRajesh, I am trying this in Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier.php file's copy function so the duplicate product not copy the qty from main product and I will set my custom qty there but it is not working, Kindly suggest what I can use. I am using M2.4.2